# FFmpeg live editing

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, live, editing

I am trying to create a video editing tool in HTML/CSS and PHP. For the video editing, I am using ffmpeg. Now, the file upload and the general editing works pretty well, but I have a problem. I would like to preview the final result inside an HTML video-tag. Thus, wenn I upload 4 clips and then select seconds 5 to 10 to be cut out, I'd like to immediately view the result so I can decide whether I want to keep it or not. Does FFmpeg support something like this? If not, what would be the best solution?

Comment: when say 5-10 sec then where does comand execute? in FFmpeg ?

Comment: I am using PHP to execute the FFmpeg commands, currently via the PHP-FFmpeg wrapper, but I could also use normal calls.

Comment: are yoy using shell_exec command? check out this link it might help you.http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#TOC41